# Open Source sound engine

Tags: c++, iphone, core-audio, openal

When I started using SoundEngine (from CrashLanding and TouchFighter), I had read about a few people recommending not to use it, for it was, according to them, not stable enough. Still it was the only solution I knew of to play sounds with pitch and position control without learning C++ and OpenAL, so I ignored the warnings and went on with it.

But now I'm starting to worry. The 2.2 SDK introduced AVFoundation. Using both SoundEngine from CrashLanding (for sounds) and AVAudioPlayer (for music), I found out SoundEngine behaves strangely when the only existing AVAudioPlayer is released (all sounds stop until a new AVAudioPlayer is initiated). Around the same time as the 2.2 SDK came out, the CrashLanding sample code was mysteriously removed from the ADC site. I'm worried there are more bad surprises to come.

My question is, is anyone aware of an Open Source alternative to SoundEngine? Maybe even a C++ library that uses OpenAL?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clunk) library, but i don't know is this what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kowalski project](http://kowalski.sourceforge.net) provides a data driven and portable sound engine that currently runs on iOS, OS X and Windows. The engine is released under the zlib license and provides positional audio, pitch control etc.

Answer (score 1):

[ObjectAL for iPhone](http://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone)

Clone it. Use it. Love it. Enjoy the freedom.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use AVFoundation?  It's pretty simple to handle and nicely flexible - apart from if you need exact timing (says the Apple documentation - but I've been testing it fairly extensively and yet to find any significant practical issues) I don't see any reason for not leveraging it.

Comment: Are you able to feed raw data into AVFoundation (AVAudioPlayer), for example if you wanted to generate and play a sine wave of a certain pitch?

Comment: There's no pitch or position control with AVFoundation.

Comment: No, but you could generate the raw sine wave data?

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation lacks sound placement.  This makes me sad.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve written a [simple sound engine](http://github.com/zoul/Finch/) around OpenAL. There are no position controls (I didn’t need them), but they would be trivial to add if you find the rest to your liking. And there is also some [experimental sound code](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/experimental/sound-engine/) in the Cocos2D engine. It has both pitch and position controls and looks quite usable.